# SharePoint change column id for REST requests

Tags: api, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I recently started experimenting with the REST API for SharePoint 2013 Foundation and I am trying to return all entries in a list. My GET request returns the data I am looking for, but the IDs used to identify the columns in the list are not helpful for identifying what the information is (see images below). The column IDs between 'Title' and 'ID', in the second image, are a jumble of characters.

[SharePoint List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ewFE.jpg)

[Response Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCYtq.jpg)

Is there any way to configure the list to use the column names as IDs? Also, is there some significance to the characters currently used as IDs?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a second request to get a listing of columns that includes the InternalName and the Title which is what you are trying to reference:

You can use this REST call:

```
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Project Details')/fields
```

or you can use CSOM:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
{
   List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Details");
   context.Load(list, l => l.Fields);
   context.ExecuteQuery();
   foreach(Field field in list.Fields)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(field.Title);
      Console.WriteLine(field.InternalName);
   }
}
```

SharePoint automatically generates the InternalName and it is a read-only field, at least using REST.  It'll be easier to get the Field Data to correlate the InternalName to the Title than changing the values.

Answer (score -1):

The column you are referring to, between Title and Id, is the ID of the content type associated to the item. It is not a column ID.

The SharePoint REST API is OData compliant, so you can use the $select parameter to query for the neccesary fields.

```
http://server/site/_api/web/lists('guid')/items?$select=Column1,Column2
```

Please be aware though, lookup fields need to be expanded as well, otherwise you get only the Id of the lookup item.

```
http://server/site/_api/web/lists('guid')/items?$select=LookupColumn&$expand=LookupColumn/Title
```